# Trying to connect to RaspberryPi jvm using JConsole

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi

Good afternoon.

I installed Java SE Embedded on my Raspberry Pi, ejre1.7.0_10, using Oracle's instructions (Getting Started with Java SE Embedded on the Raspberry Pi, Bill Courington and Gary Collins).
I can ssh into the raspi and run Java programs on it.
I now start the JVM with jmxremote arguments on the raspi with the intention of then 
starting JConsole on a Linux host computer

```
 #!/bin/bash
 ./bin/java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9999 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -jar /home/pi/test/test.jar
```

test print out integers indefinitely until the machine's limits are reached.

I do not know the correct port number. Is that the only issue?

This is pulled from the webcast Java SE Embedded Development Made Easy by Jim Connors which features my problem for a plug computer. Why doesn't JConsole work remotely (JMX) with a Raspberry Pi?
I hope that someone out there has tried this out.
If you can help, thank you.

georgefk

Comment: What is the error message you are receiving and where is the error?

Comment: Error appears in JConsole pop-up window on Linux host. Connection failed: retry? The connection to pi@192.168.1.5:9999 did not succeed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. What helped me was to start the jconole with -debug. Then I got a bit more informative error message (the message showed an error with a strange ip-address 127.0.1.1). With help from that I added this system property to my application on the pi:

-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=

And then I was successful connecting with jconsole to the pi.

Cheers, Oscar

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks Oscar! Looking at the performance stats of a tiny machine is a natural thing to be interested in. George

Comment: Changed /etc/hosts on raspi so hostname resolved to host address. Put this IP address as argument to -Djava.rmi.server.hostname      . Report success too!

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.0.173 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9004 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```